# What exactly does a relationship in ERwin DM signify?

Tags: databases

I am working on a project that requires the creation of a database. Of course we have used ERwin, which seems to be a well known tool for data modeling. My team member just completed the implementation of our database in ERwin. However, the relationships between tables do not remind of how they looked in Microsoft Access. It seems as though the relationships are just created on the entire table. In Microsoft Access, the relationships were established on attributes inside the table. I guess my only question is, what do the relationships established in ERwin signify? I assume that it just has to do something with cardinality but I could be completely wrong.

Image of ERwin DM implementation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMVH.jpg

Comment: They could be compatible representations, even if they don't look exactly the same. Impossible to know with so little information.

Comment: This is the link to the screenshot of ERwin. http://imgur.com/a/FkW16

Comment: It is important that your question is self-contained, so edit your question to add the pictures that are necessary to understand it. Images are usually not good material for our purposes, but this case I think would be an exception.